# Deflection of particle when moving out of Uniform Electric Field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

> A particle of mass **m** and charge **-q** enters a region between 2 charged plates initially moving along the **x-axis** with speed **$v_x$** .The length of the plate is **L** and uniform electric field is maintained between plates. Show that the vertical deflection of the particle at the far edge of the plate is $\frac{qEL}{2m{v_x}^2}$.Compare this motion with the motion of a projectile in a gravitational field.

My approach to solve the problem :

Since the particle is negatively charged and is moving straight between the plates , therefore the both the plates must be negatively charged. Hence I only need to consider the moment when the particle exits the plate as the initial moment for my calculations.

But at the far edge of the plates , I am unable to find the forces on the particle. Also , as I visualize it, the particle should not deflect but instead accelerate away from the plates.

But again the question tells otherwise.

Comment: When I read the problem statement (which *ought* to have a diagram of the setup), I picture the uniform electric field as being perpendicular to the $x$-axis. In fact, I picture something like a CRT in an (old-fashioned) oscilloscope where the electrons from the electron gun are deflected by (oppositely) charged plates (like [pictured here](https://circuitglobe.com/electrostatic-deflection-in-crt.html))

Comment: @AlfredCentauri , Yes that is very much probable . I went through the link and the derivations are giving an answer similar to the one asked in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Noah, consider posting an answer to your question and then accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Dgrm]

The Question asks for the value of D(deflection measured at the green surface) as shown in the diagram.

Since the Electric field is only in y-direction , therefore the force experienced by **-q** is only along the y-axis.

Therefore, by the equations of motion under constant acceleration :

$y = u_yt + \frac{1}{2}{a_yt^2}$

Since initial velocity along y is 0,

$y = \frac{1}{2}{a_yt^2}$ ----------> (1)

Now ,

$a_y = \frac{F_y}{m}$ ,where $F_y$ is force experienced by -q along the y-axis

Again ,
${F_y} = {E}{q}$ , where E is Electric field along y axis.

Therefore , $a_y = \frac{Eq}{m}$ -------------->(2)

Also , let $x$ be the horizontal distance covered by '-q'

Therefore , $x$ = ${v_x}{t}$

or, $t$ = $\frac{x}{v_x}$ --------------->(3)

Putting (2) and (3) in (1) we have

$y = \frac{Eqx^2}{2mv_x^2}$

If the green (detecting)surface is very close to the edge of the plates , then $x=L$

Hence : $y = \frac{EqL^2}{2mv_x^2}$

This equation can also be represented as $y=kx^2$  where k represents all the constants.

This equation is an equation of a parabola , Similar to the equation of motion of a  body falling under gravity.